How to determine that users input data (via soft keyboard, physical keyboard, or scanner) into an Edit Text field within my Jetpack Compose App?
I have an Android application with an Edit Text box that can take input from a physical keyboard (if it's on the device), a soft keyboard, and a scanner. In order to handle scanner input differently from standard keyboard input, I must be able to differentiate between these input types. In particular, I would like to know if the latest entry entered into the Edit Text field was typed or scanned. How can I achieve this distinction on Android?
I have tried by checking the speed of the input. Barcode scanners are much faster then typed input but that is failed in many cases, i want a good approach to tackle this problem

If you can monitor key events, perhaps this will help.

How are you scanning the input? Sharing that can help understand the scenario better.

I'm scanning input using physical scanners on Zebra devices, and I've tried using key events, but it doesn't seem to be a reliable approach to me and may fail in some cases.
